# My select code styling works in firefox but not in ie

Tags: html, css

The Link
http://ferrenetwork.com/weavechanges/dataentry.html

Here is the html code that im using

```
<select id="box1View" multiple="multiple">
   <option>2008-2009 "Mini" Baja</option>
   <option>AAPA - Asian American Psychological Association</option>
   <option>Agape</option>
   <option>AGE-Alliance for Graduate Excellence</option>
   <option>AICHE (American Inst of Chemical Engineers)</option>
</select>
```

This is the styling im using in my css

```
#box1View{width:350px; height:350px; border:1px solid #CDCDCD; }
#box1View option {background:#E6E6E6; border: 1px solid #fff; padding: 15px 0 15px 5px;cursor:pointer;}
#box1View option:hover {background:#e0f0f5; cursor:pointer;}
```

Comment: why is my style not working in ie or chrome but working in firefox

Comment: I am seeing a difference between Chrome and FF, not sure why. Just wanted to confirm that @RafaelFernandezJr. isn't crazy.
http://jsfiddle.net/GfqKj/

Comment: You can't actually style `<option>` tags.   Some browsers may let you, but it's non-standard behavior.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `Except for background-color and color, style settings applied through the style object for the option element are ignored`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Make that an answer, because it is right.

Answer (score 2):

Form elements are normally rendered by the OS and not by the browser.  This means that styling them doesn't always work.  It may in some browsers, but it's non-standard behavior.

`<option>` tags can't actually be styled.  This is by design, unfortunately.

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (under the *Remarks* section):

> Except for `background-color` and `color`, style settings applied through the style object for the option element are ignored.

Comment: thats a bummer :-( first time i have run into that issue

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  To get what you want, you'll have to make your own drop down.